# Center the text in a DIV who's height is set with percentage

Tags: html, css

This is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2EFZK/1/). I can't vertically center the texts `Name1`,  `Name2` and the time text. I did try with `display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;` but it didn't help. Can you point me where am I doing it wrong?

**html:**

```
<div style="height: 15%;">
    <div class="timeDiv">
        <span class="time">19:00</span>
    </div>

    <div class="titleDiv">
            <img src="" alt="test1 img">                        
        <span class="title">Name 1</span>
    </div>            

    <div class="titleDiv">                                        
        <img src="" alt="test2 img">
        <span class="title">Name2</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**css**:

```
img{
    height: 80%; 
    float:left; 
    margin-left: 7%;
    margin-right: 1%;   
}

.timeDiv{
    float: left; 
    width:10%;
}

.titleDiv{
    float: left; 
    width: 45%;            
}

.title{
    font-size: 2em;
    float: left;
}

.time{
    font-size: 1.5em;
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: `display:table-cell` needs an ascendant with at least a `display:table`, or `table-row`. Just note that it will make it behave as a table (which may provide unexpected results, eg: losing things like word-wrap). This sort of feels like it's tabular data, though, so why not just use a table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look here :) http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html

It explains why not to use `vertical-align: middle` for block level elements and shows you how to do what you want (near the bottom of the page).

> The problem here is three-fold:
>
> HTML layout traditionally was not designed to specify vertical behavior. By its very nature, it scales width-wise, and the content flows to an appropriate height based on the available width.
>
> Traditionally, horizontal sizing and layout is easy; vertical sizing
>   and layout was derived from that. The reason vertical-align:middle
>   isn't doing what is desired want is because the author doesn't
>   understand what it's supposed to do, but …
>
> … this is because the CSS
>   specification really screwed this one up (in my
>   opinion)—vertical-align is used to specify two completely different
>   behaviors depending on where it is used.

I believe method 1 will do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You could try applying `line-height`s to specific containers. Your img will get `2 em`, the times will get `1.33 em` and your title will get `1 em`, although this is redundant because the default line-height is 1em. Here is an example:

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/Cael6/2EFZK/3/)

GL :)